# Search Engine Ping Services?

Tags: search-engine

i'm looking for a good ping service like [pingomatic.com](http://pingomatic.com) but for general website (not necessarily a blog).

Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I just came across a massive list of services:
http://readymadeweb.com/2010/01/01/242-ways-to-ping-how-to-stay-on-search-engine-radar/

Answer (score 0):

Search Engine Ping is the leading SEO tool on the internet that gets your website, blog or affiliate links ranked quickly and at the highest results in search engines! 
recommend this service
http://statstool.com/search-engine-ping/